# Change the class of another class' instance

Tags: angular, typescript, typescript2.4

I have a Angular 4 Typescript app that have multiple types of objects defined by classes that have different type properties, as below:

```
export class Fruit {
  name: string;
  type: string;

  constructor(columnName: string) {
    this.name = columnName;
  }
}

export class Apple extends Fruit {
  /* additional properties */

 constructor(name: string) {
    super(name);
  }

  get type(): string {
    return 'apple';
  }
}

export class Orange extends Fruit {
  /* additional properties different from Apple */

 constructor(name: string) {
    super(name);
  }

  get type(): string {
    return 'Orange';
  }
}
```

These objects belong to a basket object in an array member, like fruits in a basket. I would like to be able to dynamically set the kind of fruit via a dropdown in a form. Every time I do that, I get:

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot set property type of [object Object] which has only a getter
```

I'm new to Typescript and I reckon I'm doing an advance thing already, but this is something required for a project I'm doing.

---

EDIT:

I use ng-formly to generate my form elements. The relevant html looks like this:

```
<form class="formly" role="form" [formGroup]="fruitBasket" novalidate>
  <div formArrayName="fruits">
    <div *ngFor="let control of fruitBasketForm.controls.fruits.controls; let i = index">
      <formly-form
        [model]="fruitBasket.fruits[i]"
        [fields]="fruitFields[i]"
        *ngIf="i === currFruitIndex">
      </formly-form>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: What does your dropdown code look like? How do you set the type? Btw if you are depending on types on an inheritance architecture, what's the meaning of using inheritance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this example your super class should have a setter since there is a name collision in your `type` field

```
export class Fruit {
  name: string;
  type: string;

  constructor(columnName: string) {
    this.name = columnName;
  }

  set type(type){
    this.type = type;
  }
}
```

But the real usage of inheritance is that every object should know which class they belong to and use the method in their classes. If you are depending on a `type` property in an inheritance architecture you are not really using the full power of inheritance.

Comment: That makes sense. Leaning now towards using only the Fruit super class and just differentiate them using the type property.

I wanted to use classes since different fruit objects may have different methods I haven't figured out yet.